# How are people handling connection loss through downscaling in amazon auto scaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services

As I understand it, when Amazon auto scaling groups downscale, any connections open to the terminated instance are just lost - there is no graceful termination.

I'm wondering how others are handling this.

My thinking is that the initiator of the connection should handle the failure as it should be able to deal with the situation where an instance fails rather than being deliberately terminated.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did it is with a lifecycle hook. Which can interrupt the termination process for a set amount of time (default 1 hour).

It is designed to be resumed once your work is complete but the timeout worked for a hacky connection draining.

> You have the option of adding a hook to your Auto Scaling group
>   instances in this state into a Terminating:Wait state. This state
>   allows you to access these instances before they are terminated.

source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AutoScalingGroupLifecycle.html

con: setup via CLI, but not too bad.

How to do that:
    http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/adding-lifecycle-hooks.html

When creating IAM you will need this policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
        "autoscaling:DeleteLifecycleHook",
        "autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat",
        "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
        "autoscaling:DescribeAutoscalingGroups",
        "autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks",
        "autoscaling:PutInstanceInStandby",
        "autoscaling:PutInstanceInService",
        "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
        "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
        "iam:CreateRole",
        "iam:PassRole",
        "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
        "ec2:Describe*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Seems like a good solution - can you confirm that when an instance goes into Terminating:Wait state it is still able to respond to in-flight requests?

Comment: I just assumed it worked and initial testing appears that is not the case. :/ thank for the good question. I'll post back if I get it working.

Comment: I misunderstood in flight requests with activate sessions. I wanted it to give me a grace period for the sessions to naturally die off. (This doesn't work.) it appears to finish current requests.

Comment: it was finishing current requests that my original question was concerned with. I would assume that consumers are able to handle the case where a session become invalid for whatever reason (through expiry or the session being lost on the server side). In my current work we are using Redis to hold session data so I'm not concerned about losing sessions.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. I ended up just adding session info to the DB and everything works great.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a load balancer you can switch on the connection draining option on the Instances tab. It allows you to set a time to wait for connections to be closed before terminating the instance. Max is 3600 seconds. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-connection-draining-remove-instances-from-service-with-care/

Comment: I'm guessing this feature has been added in the 3 years since I asked the original question ;-)

Comment: Yes I suppose so. I Hope it helps someone who has the same problem as you did :)

Answer (score 1):

You usually use an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) in front of your auto-scaled instances. The load balancer will stop sending requests to an instance that is about to be terminated. If you use for example the following format:

```
as-put-scaling-policy MyScaleDownPolicy --auto-scaling-group MyAutoScalingGroup  --adjustment=-1 --type ChangeInCapacity  --cooldown 300
```

You will get enough time for your instance to finish processing the requests that it had, before it is being terminated.

See more details here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SetUpASLBApp.html

Note that you should have an ELB group to these instances. From [AWS Auto-scaling docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AS_Concepts.html):

> After Auto Scaling determines which specific instance to terminate, it
>   checks to see whether the instance is part of an Elastic Load
>   Balancing group. If so, Auto Scaling instructs the load balancer to
>   remove the instance from the load balancing group and waits for the
>   removal to complete. If Auto Scaling determines that the instance is
>   not part of an Elastic Load Balancing group, Auto Scaling attempts to
>   terminate the instance by running system shutdown scripts.

Comment: That's a good answer, but I'm not sure that's what the OP described as the scenario: after the connection is routed through the load balancer, and the server downscales out, there could be connections open to that server. The cooldown stops further scaling AFTER a previous action has occured. But if there is a downscaling action occuring isolated, targetting an instance with open connections, they will be lost.

Comment: that's exactly my question. I'm wondering whether anyone has any clever ways to deal with this other than leaving it to the requestor to handle to error.

Answer (score 0):

There's no solution in the search space of EC2/AutoscalingGroups. I wouldn't assume that waiting for removal from ELB to complete means waiting for existing connections to close. ELBs do enforce their own non-configurable timeouts, but even assuming that the group will wait that out when ELB reports any open connections is optimistic.

A potential answer is to branch out to other AWS offerings, like SQS and SNS. These two can stand in for most of a termination policy because they can also be triggered by CloudWatch alarms. The missing pieces are worker selection, cooldown, and resetting the alarm.